# Laravel Maatwebsite excel

Tags: laravel

I need your help. I don't know how to import the excel file. I mean I don't understand where to put this users.xlsx and how to get its directory

```
 public function import()
        {
            Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');

            return redirect('/')->with('success', 'All good!');
        }
```

Comment: you have to upload a xls file and then import

Comment: where to upload the file , i mean in which folder ?

Comment: I mean through file upload in form if file is dynamic. if your xls file is not dynamic then add the file inside public directory and access it with public_path() helper function

Comment: I am trying to put it int public directory     :         Excel::import(new UsersImport, request()->file(public_path('users.xlsx')));
 but it says storage/logs/laravel-2019-05-03.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: it's about file permission issue check that

Comment: is there a way  i can get it from desktop please ?

Comment: Your permission denied error means the permissions on the `storage` or `storage/logs` folder isn't correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others.

Comment: Now it says Interface 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel' not found

Comment: You are missing the "use" statement in your UsersImport class. Also, I believe the default behavior is to check the storage directory for the file if you use it the way you did in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its simple on mattwebsite you need a controller like below :

```
  public function importExcel(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('import_file')) {
        Excel::load($request->file('import_file')->getRealPath(), function ($reader) {
            foreach ($reader->toArray() as $key => $row) {
// note that these fields are completely different for you as your database fields and excel fields so replace them with your own database fields
                $data['title'] = $row['title'];
                $data['description'] = $row['description'];
                $data['fax'] = $row['fax'];
                $data['adrress1'] = $row['adrress1'];
                $data['telephone1'] = $row['telephone1'];
                $data['client_type'] = $row['client_type'];


                if (!empty($data)) {
                    DB::table('clients')->insert($data);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Session::put('success on import');

    return back();
}
```

and a view like this :

```
                <form
                  action="{{ URL::to('admin/client/importExcel') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2">excel import</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="uploader"><input type="file"  name="import_file" class="file-styled"><span class="action btn btn-default legitRipple" style="user-select: none;">choose file</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
            </form>
```

and finally a route like below :

```
Route::post('admin/client/importExcel', 'ClientController@importExcel');
```

Comment: It says to me "Undefined index: name"

Comment: @alphal consider that you should have the name both in database and in excel file and those fields as you may know are here                 $data['name'] = $row['name'];